# Can't launch Appium from cmd

Tags: appium

I use *appium-desktop-setup-1.8.2*.

On Windows I start it from the console with such options:

```
appium
appium -p 4724
start appium
```

But I only have the Appium launch window open. Appium doesn't start automatically. It have to run it manually.

What am I doing wrong?

I don't understand this response:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium>appium -U 0b36774b032fbdba -p 4724

C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium>
Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated, and will be removed in  React v16.0. Use the latest available v15.* prop-types package from npm instead. For info on usage, compatibility, migration and more, see https://github.com/facebook/prop-types#prop-types
Warning: Accessing createClass via the main React package is deprecated, and will be removed in React v16.0. Use a plain JavaScript class instead. If you're not yet ready to migrate, create-react-class v15.* is available on npm as a temporary, drop-in replacement. For more info see https://github.com/facebook/prop-types#prop-types
(node:10212) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
```

Comment: Thanks to all for response.
I found the same issue on https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/issues/181

There's no automatic server startup configuration for Appium Desktop. The only way is to run it from the command line which requires a Node installation.

Answer (score 0):

As from official APPIUM documentation **-U** options is deprecated now!! Thats why you are getting error

to start appium , you can simply type

```
appium -p 4723
```

However , it seems that your objective is to create an appium session with a device as well.

in below blog i have mentioned how to make request to appium using Robot Framework, However, you can just have a look and implement in any language.

https://automationlab0000.wordpress.com/2018/08/21/first-automation-script-using-robot-framework/

Comment: Thanks, but it's only suitable only for Node installation, not for Desktop. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

To start appium server you can use

```
appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723
```

Make sure port 4723 is not used by any other process. To check use

```
netstat –aon | find "4723"
```

You can find processId from above code. To terminate the process:

```
taskkill /F /pid processID
```

Then you can use **appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723** to start appium server.

Comment: Thanks, but it's only suitable only for Node installation, not for Desktop. I don't understand why.

Comment: To start appium server in appium desktop, First you need to open appium desktop app. Then you need to set **host = 127.0.0.1** and **port = 4723**. And Click start server button in appium desktop.